# Stop multiple AJAX requests in same page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made a web page, on load of which an AJAX request is fired which brings in data and then updates that page.

Now everything is working fine except the ajax request is fired every time page is loaded even though the content on the server is not changed. So how can I optimize this process so that page doesn't fire ajax request again and again ?

the code process works as follows

I check for the url using regex
courseInfoRegexUrl = /(http|ftp|https)://[\w]+/[\w]+/courses/course(.php|)?/gi;

if it matches then I call a function with an arg, the function is as follows :-

```
function getCourseData(name){
    $.ajax({
        url : "api/getCourseData.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {name:name, token:catoken},
        success : function(d){
            d = JSON.parse(d);
            console.log(d);
            getCourseReviews(name);

        },
        error : function(error){
            generalErrorShow("Some error ocurred. Try refreshing the page");
        }
    });
}
```

its call example is getCourseData("comp1");

Thanks

Comment: Have your server tell the browser to cache the response by sending a `Cache-Control` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use websocket .

Or do a checksum file, and tell to ajax to download the checksum file . So you can save data . But, without websocket, you need ajax request every times for update your content